# How to move a box [ rectangle as square] up and down in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to move a box up and down in `pygame`.
I can move the box left using key `a` and right using key `d`.
How can I move it up and down?
My code:

```
import sys
import pygame as pg


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    rect = pg.Rect(300, 220, 20, 20)
    velocity = (0, 0)
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True

        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_a]:  #to move left
            rect.x -= 4
        if keys[pg.K_d]: #to move right
            rect.x += 4


        screen.fill((40, 40, 40))
        pg.draw.rect(screen, (150, 200, 20), rect)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same logic as the horizontal move, by changing y coordinates :

```
        y-4
         |
x-4 <-- [_] --> x+4
         |
        y+4


if keys[pg.K_w]: # to move up
    rect.y -= 4
if keys[pg.K_s]: # to move down
    rect.y += 4
```

Comment: I have another question , **How can I set boundaries for it?**

Comment: @user8455923 do you want to set boundaries on the gamescreen or it has to be smaller, like if the box could move only in a specific cell ?

Answer (score -1):

I think pressing of arrow keys would make more sense for moving box.

(Inside while not done: loop)

```
if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
        rect.x -= 4
    if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
        rect.x += 4
    if event.key == pg.K_UP:
        rect.y -= 4
    if event.key == pg.K_DOWN:
        rect.y += 4
```

Comment: I am not using arrow keys because they will not let move the box continuously.

Comment: We can also use `if keys[pygame.K_UP]:` and others .